# MISRA C: 2004: typedefs that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic types

Tags: c, type-safety, misra

I have this MISRA C:2004 violation `typedefs that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic types`

for example I have this piece of code, where I did not understand the right solution to avoid this violation

```
static int handlerCalled = 0;

int llvm_test_diagnostic_handler(void) {
  LLVMContextRef C = LLVMGetGlobalContext();
  LLVMContextSetDiagnosticHandler(C, &diagnosticHandler, &handlerCalled);
```

Comment: it probably wants you to used the `stdint.h` types, such as `int32_t` if you want a 32-bit signed int rather than `int`.

Comment: OP: is the line your MISRA-checker complains about, the one initializing handlerCalled : `static int handerCalled = 0;` ? If so, I am quite sure that @ChristianGibbons is correct in his assumption.

Comment: Thanks I tried to add "#include <stdint.h>; typedef int uint32_t; " and I corrected using "static uint32_t handlerCalled = 0;" "uint32_t llvm_test_diagnostic_handler(void)" and now works!

Comment: Not quite, @GianniSpear.  You *should* `#include <stdint.h>`, but you ***should not*** write your own typedef for `uint32_t`.  Use the typedefs provided by the header, as they are the ones that you can rely upon to be correct for your particular system.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger. I did not get your help. Could you make an easy example please? (I am very new about MISRA-C rules). Thanks in advance

Comment: `uint32_t` is intended for unsigned 32-bit numbers, and therefore should never be typedeffed to an `int`, which is signed.  Such mistakes are one reason why, as @JohnBollinger strongly suggested, you should not be doing the typedefs yourself.  `stdint.h` already does all of the typedefs for you.  Just include the header and use the types it defines.

Comment: The best option is to use MISRA-C:2012 and C99 (or newer), unless stuck with an older tool chain. Solves a whole lot of problems - this would have been a non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MISRA rule is aimed at the fact that C does not define the exact size, range, or representation of its standard integer types.  The `stdint.h` header mitigates this issue by providing [several families of typedefs](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1) expressing the implementation-supported integer types that provide specific combinations of signedness, size, and representation.  Each C implementation provides a `stdint.h` header appropriate for that implementation.

You should comply with the MISRA rule by using the types defined in your implementation's `stdint.h` header, choosing the types that meet your needs from among those it actually supports (or those you expect it to support).  For example, if you want a signed integer type exactly 32 bits wide, with no padding bits, and expressed in two's complement representation, then that is `int32_t` -- if your implementation provides that at all (it would be surprising, but not impossible, for such a type not to be available).

For example,

```
#include <stdint.h>

// relies on the 'int32_t' definition from the above header:
static int32_t handlerCalled = 0;
```

The point I was raising in my comment was that you seemed to say that you not only included the header, but also defined *your own* typedef for `uint32_t`.  ***You must not define your own typedef*** for this or other types in the scope of `stdint.h`.  At best it is redundant to do so, but at worst it satisfies the MISRA checker yet breaks your code.

Comment: MISRA-C:2004 supports C90 only. `stdint.h` isn't likely available. The appropriate course of action then is to write some pre-processor stuff checking `#if defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L #include <stdint.h> #else typedef ...`. For this reason MISRA-C:2004 doesn't say what kind of types that should be used in place of the default ones. In the current MISRA-C:2012 Directive 4.6, stdint.h is explicitly recommended.